# jquery mobile 1.4 page multipage onpagecreate management to avoid double triggers fires

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, triggers, multipage

Can someone clear out the usage of event handlers in multipage? Documentation is good but don't warn about the possible conflicts that may arise if you mix the things.

For example, as a newbie I noticed that I get double fire triggering if I place my event handlers in this html structure, that comes out from the logic following (or at this point overlooking) the docs:

```
<body>
<div data-role="panel" id="panel">...</div>
<div data-role="page" id="page1" data-title="myhomePage">...</div>
<div data-role="page" id="page2" data-title="products">...</div>
<div data-role="page" id="page3" data-title="settings">...</div>
</body>
```

with the following code in the my.js where all the handlers are in the global page (as shown and copied from the doc examples).

```
$(document).on('pagecreate' ,function(){...event handlers for buttons etc...}); //for the body // ( which is for me actually wrong!!!)
$(document).on('pagecreate', '#page1' ,function(){...}); //for home page
$(document).on('pagecreate', '#page2' ,function(){...}); //for product page
```

Now, I had an intuition and found a solution in the middle of the try and error by removing the global onpagecreate and markup all the event handlers inside page1.

So now in the Javascript I have only:

```
$(document).on('pagecreate', '#page1' ,function(){...all my event handlers here...}); 
//for home page

$(document).on('pagecreate', '#page2' ,function(){...generateLists()...}); 
//for the product page
```

And all double events that I was struggling with for days are gone.

But still unsure if I am on the right way as I miss some real solid examples, from the doc.

I also have a complain about the examples in the API documentation methods. I hardly understand the majority of the examples. They are all based on abstract concepts, not on something real usually found on a web app or page, which is really complicating the whole learning process (at least for me).

Comment: `$(document).on('pagecreate', '#page1'` you forgot hashtag `#page_ID`.

Comment: Thanks Omar, sorry, jus' correct ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you have tasks that always have to be done, and others based on the page type, you could achieve it like this:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "div[data-role=page]", function(event){
    // Every time a page is being created

    if ($(this).attr("id") == "page1") {
        // Only when on #page1
    }
});
```

`$(this)` in here is the page on which the creation event has been fired, so you can use it to manipulate itself; it's better to use `div[data-role=page]` as selector to attach the handler only to divs that have `data-role=page`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute functions on all pages, bind it to `pagecreate`. It will run once for each page created. It's recommened to bind `click` etc... events on `pagecreate`.

Also, note that `pageinit` is deprecated as of jQM 1.4 and replaced with `pagecreate`.

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", function () {
  // functions
});
```

If you want to run specific functions for specific pages, you need to bind it to *page id*.

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page_ID", function () {
  // functions
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/gbg43/)**

Comment: Ciao Omar, thanks again. The difference is quite clear, but with this scheme when on real device (iOS for sure) I get triggers twice. If you navigate within pages, you just add one more fire per click for each change of page. I comment // $(document).on("pagecreate", function () {...}); put all the buttons and swipes event selectors in #page1 and the multiple fires vanished, and all runs smooth.

Comment: @sasha if you use same selectors in all pages, you'll definitely have multiple triggers. Use `$(this).find('selector').on('event'`