# jquery mobile input label button

Tags: events, jquery-mobile, button, input, label

I have some problem.

This is HTML document.

```
<input class="input" type='checkbox' id='ev_1' name='ev_1' checked='checked'/>
<label for='ev_1'>
<button class='ui-btn custom-btn' id='issue'>On</button>
</label>
```

This is javascript.

```
$("#issue").click(function(event){
    alert("!");
}
```

I think that alert("!"); is occur when I click button.
But, not effect....

I want to show alert("!");
I need your help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21259873/1771795 why are you wrapping button in label? wrap input-checkbox instead.

Comment: is possible wrapping input-checkbox??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Omar mentioned, your button should be outside the label and your input checkbox can be inside the label:

```
<label for='ev_1'>
    <input class="input" type='checkbox' id='ev_1' name='ev_1' checked='checked' />On
</label>
<button class='ui-btn custom-btn' id='issue'>On</button>
```

Then you can have event handlers defined in the jQM pagecreate handler. To handle the checkbox, use a change event handler, and for the button a click handler:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page1", function () {
    $("#issue").on("click", function (event) {
        alert("Button Click");
    });

    $("#ev_1").on("change", function (event) {
        alert("Checkbox Change");
    });
});
```

> Here is a working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/x4r8t1fy/)**

Comment: I want button in label... ^^

Comment: @YongchanJo, what are you trying to achieve by having the button inside label?  You can do it, but clicking the button will also change the checkbox: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/x4r8t1fy/1/

Comment: Wow, Thanks for your attention.
$("#issue").on("click", function (event) {
        alert("Button Click");
        return false;
    });